# InappBroser Phonegap abrindo URL no Chrome

Tags: android, ios, apache-cordova, app, inappbrowser

Estou usando o inappbrowser no phonegap pra abrir um link externo dentro do meu app.

Uso desta forma

```
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://google.com', '_blank', 'location=no');
```

quando eu abro o phonegap desktop e emulo ele no meu celular, funciona direitinho, porém quando eu gero apk e instalo a url externa abre no navegador do meu celular (chrome) e não abre dentro do app.

Já usei todos os targets descritos na documentação.

Como resolver?